# Countdown for loop counting up

Tags: javascript

The alert is counting up not down!

```
function loop() {
    for (var t = 32; t > 0; t--) {
        (function (t) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                I_1(t);
            }, 200);
        })(t);
    }
}
function I_1(amt) {
    alert(amt);
}
```

Comment: Worksforme. But why are you using `alert` in a countdown, and why are you scheduling all alerts at the same time?

Comment: it works (counts down) except of timing which doesn't work as expected (I assume it should count down every 200ms- it's not)

Comment: that's what I've just said ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are starting all the timeouts at once. The actual order that they will be executed depends on how the events are implemented internally in each browser.

Give them different delays so that they start one after the other:

```
var time = 200;
for (var t=32;t>0;t--){
  (function(t) {
    setTimeout(function() { I_1(t); }, time);
    time += 200;
  })(t);
}
```